# Why is the singular verb "is" used with two things in this sentence?

Tags: verbs

> There are more than 700 million cell phones used in the US today and at least 140 million of those cell phone users will abandon their current phone for a new phone every 14-18 months. I’m not one of those people who just “must” have the latest phone. Actually, I use my cell phone until the  battery no longer holds a good charge. At that point, it’s time. So I figure I’ll just get a replacement battery. But I’m told that battery is no longer made and the phone is no longer
> manufactured because **there’s** newer technology and better features in the latest phones. That’s a typical justification. The phone wasn’t even that old; maybe a little over one year? I’m just one example. Can you imagine how many countless other people have that same scenario? No wonder cell phones take the lead when it comes to “e-waste.”

*Newer technology and better features* is a plural noun phrase. Should *are* be used in this sentence?
Is *there's newer technology and **(there are)** better features in the latest phones* possible?

Comment: See the hot debate at https://english.stackexchange.com/q/573727/425655 and the posts that it links.

Comment: One important thing to note: If you take a different context and ignore the issue here of the idiom that can use "there is" even for plurals: You suggested that maybe the verb should be "are" because both phrases are plurals. But if we had a simpler sentence: "My dogs and cats are hungry," then "are" isn't plural because the dogs and cats are, but because your sentence has two subjects. You would also use plural for "My dog and my cat are hungry."

Answer (score 1):

For many English speakers, *There's* has become an invariable word, irrespective of whether it introduces a singular or plural item.

See [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/w/index.php?title=there%27s#Usage_notes), which gives an example from Lennon and McCartney: "Imagine there’s no countries."

**Edit**: or a quote used as a headline in a major Irish newspaper: [‘There’s hundreds of kids going to Center Parcs yet we can’t run a camp for 25 of them’](https://www.independent.ie/world-news/coronavirus/theres-hundreds-of-kids-going-to-center-parcs-yet-we-cant-run-a-camp-for-25-of-them-40647253.html)

Comment: Correct, and +1, though an example that's not song lyrics would hold more weight.

Comment: Example added, @gotube. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You are technically correct.

> There are new technology and new features

is grammatically correct.

What is happening here is called ellipsis. What is really meant is

> There is new technology, and there are new features

This gets shortened to

> There is new technology and new features

If you reverse the order of the nouns, no one would make the mistake

> There are new features and new technology

Comment: This misses that it's now common to use "there's" with plural nouns, like "*There's apples in the fridge*".

Answer (score 0):

You are quite right. It's the kind of grammatical error many of us make in informal speech and no-one minds too much. There are many UK dialects where "There's loads of them" and "There's people queuing" are heard more often than their grammatically correct versions.

Btw, your re-wording is rather cumbersome. "The latest phones use newer technology and have better features" might be neater.